# Extract data from topic (ar_pose)

Tags: ros, topic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I am trying to get data from ar_pose_markers. I am running the package and I see the topic is refreshing with new data. I am using ar_tools and usb_cam.

I have to make a node that subscribe to this topic and it able to extract the information. I am subscribing to the topic but I can extract the position.  This code give me a number but is the same number all the time.

The node code is the following one

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "std_msgs/String.h"
#include <ar_pose/ARMarkers.h>



int yo=10;
int zo;
int i=0;
void ar_pose_markerCallback(const ar_pose::ARMarkers::ConstPtr& msg)
{
float xo=0;
ROS_INFO("hello world");
ar_pose::ARMarker ar_pose_marker;
xo=ar_pose_marker.pose.pose.orientation.x;
ROS_INFO("%d", xo);


}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
ROS_INFO("hello world");
ros::init(argc, argv, "node_sub");
ros::NodeHandle n;
ros::Rate loop_rate(1);
ros::Subscriber sub = n.subscribe("ar_pose_marker", 1, ar_pose_markerCallback);
while (ros::ok())
```

{

```
ros::spinOnce();
loop_rate.sleep();
```

}
return 0;
}

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/257806/extract-data-from-topic-(ar_pose)/) by [jsoley](https://answers.ros.org/users/29811/jsoley/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-03-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [angeltop](https://answers.ros.org/users/29793/angeltop/) on 2017-03-27**:
Try the following:

xo=ar_pose_marker.pose.pose.orientation.x;

xo=msg->pose.pose.orientation.x;

You do not use the received data in your code, instead you use the initial value from the constructor of the marker.

**Comment by [Mikku](https://answers.ros.org/users/32618/mikku/) on 2017-11-23**:
Can you write this in Python. Thanks. I wanted to know the current position of my markers and then I have to move my drone to the next way point which is a 3D position.

**Comment by [angeltop](https://answers.ros.org/users/29793/angeltop/) on 2017-11-23**:
@Mikku You can follow the tutorial : http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28python%29#rospy_tutorials.2BAC8-Tutorials.2BAC8-WritingPublisherSubscriber.Writing_the_Subscriber_Node

**Comment by [Mikku](https://answers.ros.org/users/32618/mikku/) on 2017-11-23**:
Sir I have done that and made my Python file. But I don't want to use callback function. Because when I have to move the drone to the different point . The changes I am doing in the callback function is not being reflected on the main program. I am therefore looking for an another way to find poses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

if you have only using one marker, with your camera try using the below command to fetch x;

> msg->markers[0].pose.pose.position.x

if you want orientation, replace "position" with "orientation"

---

Originally posted by [saikishor](https://answers.ros.org/users/21247/saikishor/) with karma: 228 on 2017-03-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0